# cross sum that alternates between + and -

Tags: haskell

This is the code i already wrote. I am able to get the cross sum of an integer.

```
module Blueprint where
import Prelude

crosssum :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
crosssum i n 
    |n < 1*10^i = n
    |otherwise = let(d,m)=n`divMod` (1*10^i)  in  m + crosssum i d 


crosssumalt :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
crosssumalt i n 
    |n < 1*10^i = n
    |n < 0 = let(d,m)=n`divMod`(1*10^i) in  m + crosssumalt i d 
    |otherwise = let(d,m)=n`divMod`(1*10^i) in  m - crosssumalt i d 


gencrosssum :: Integer -> Bool -> Integer -> Integer
gencrosssum i bool n
    |bool==False=crosssum i n   
    |otherwise=crosssumalt i n
```

My problem is that if the user types the Bool "True" in the parameters it is supposed to do: 54321=-5 + 43 - 21 = 17 or 1234567 = 1 - 234 + 567 = 334. False is the the normal cross sum. So gencrosssum  True  54321 gives me -17 instead of 17 (its supposed to always give out a positive Integer). My idea would be to just put a guard in crossumalt that would turn a negative into a positive, but nesting guards in guards gives me parse errors. Maybe someone would be so kind to give me a better solotion or show me how i can put a guard in gencrosssum that turns negatives into positives.

Comment: what about using `otherwise = abs (crosssumalt i n)`? Also this is borderline unreadable - please use camelCase (`genCrossSum`) and `| bool == False` is `| not bool` and `bool` is not a good name IMO - what about renaming `bool` into `allPlus` (`notAlternating` would lead into `not notAtlernating`)

Comment: BTW: I have some doubts about your `crosssumalt` ... have you tested this?

Comment: also: *what* is a cross sum exactly (never heard of it)

Comment: I have to use the parameters Integer Bool Interger because its given in the task by my professor. Cross sum is another word for Digit sum which means you add every digit of the number.

Comment: but you don't have to name them `bool` (right?)

Comment: btw: then why isn't `crosssumalt 54321 = -5 + 4 -3 +2 -1 = -3`

Comment: there are 2 parameters given to crosssumalt 1 54321 would be -5 + 4 -3 +2 -1 = -3 and  crosssumalt 2 54321 would be 21 - 43 + 5 = -17. For 2 as first parameter it adds the degits in steps of 2 for 1 it does a normal digit sum. Btw Calling abs on my genCrossSum works well. Thank you for telling me about it.